# Number of $n$-digit permutations with exactly $n-2$ digits smaller than the next

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

> How many permutations of $1,2,\cdots, n$ contain exactly $n-2$ digits that are smaller than the digit immediately to their right?

My solution proceeded with recursion. It has some chance of being wrong.

We call all such permutations **good permutations**. We call a digit **good** if it is  are smaller than the next digit. Let $f(n)$ denote the number of good permutations of $1,2, \cdots ,n$. Note that a good permutation has exactly  $n-2$ digits.

Consider any good permutation of $1,2,\cdots ,n+1$. Remove $1$ from the permutation. Note that this can decrease the number of good digits  by at most $1$. We have two cases :

$1)$**Number of good digits remain the same:**

Since the original permutation was good, the new permutation has exactly $(n+1)-2=n-1$ good digits, but has only $n$ digits. But $n+1$ can never be a good digit, since it can never be smaller than any other digit. Hence, after removing $1$, each of $2,3,4, \cdots ,n$ is a good digit. But the only such permutation is $2$ $3$ $\cdots$ $n+1$. Now note that putting back $1$ does not increase or change the number of good digits (unless we put it at the start). Hence, there are exactly $n$ places where $1$ can go.

$2)$**Number of good digits decreases:**

Since the number of good digits can decrease by at most $1$, in this case, the new permutation has exactly $n-2$ good digits. But there are exactly $f(n)$ of these permutations. When we put back $1$, we cannot place it in any of the following positions because then the number of good digits does not increase:

**A)** After a good digit itself

**B)** At the end

There are exactly two places to put $1$ in then. So there are $2f(n)$ permutations in this case.

Combining, we get, $f(n+1)=2f(n)+n$

Is this right?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. The closed-form solution is $f(n)=2^n-n-1$

Comment: Hmm thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Your solution seems complex. It can be done more simply - [My Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2125333/306625)
From my answer it is easy to find general formula.
$$f(n) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n-1}\left\{\binom{n}{i} - 1 \right\} = 2^n-n-1$$
This problem is used in some BdMO Regionals 2015 with $n = 7,8,9$.